# why the output of this program comes only by using extern ? Why not without it?

Tags: output, extern

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int main ()
{

   printf("%d\n",z);
   return 0;

}  
int z=25;
```

> why is output to this code is showing an error ?

Comment: Is this C or C++? Please add a tag.

Comment: Sorry , i forget to mention that.It is C. Although i have got my answer, but is it going to effect whether it is C or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **order in which you declare your functions/variables count in C**. In your code, when the compiler parses your code, it encounters the symbol `z`, which has not yet been declared.

So, you need to put your `int z = ...` before the first time you use z, hence before main.

The `extern` keyword tells the compiler that the variable has been declared in another file, so it will be resolved during linking, i.e. when all the files are assembled into a program. So for the compilation of this file, the unresolved symbol `z` can be ignored => no compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>  
int z=25;

int main ()
{

   printf("%d\n",z);
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: As z was not declared above main, the main function did not know that a variable z has been declared .In C Programming all functions and variables  which are going to be used by main function It must be declared before main in order for the main function to perform the required operations.